# How do I create files using the lines in a .txt file?

Tags: shell

For example I have a file called fileNames.txt.  `cat >fileNames` returns

```
abet

able

abacus
```

How do I use fileNames to create abet, able, and abacus as .txt files?  I tried using pipes with cat and touch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do that, including the following (assuming GNU `xargs`):

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' -e 's/$/.txt/' fileNames.txt | xargs -rd '\n' touch --
```

This assumes that there is only one filename per line in fileNames.txt.  The `sed` script deletes blank lines (thanks to @rubynorails) and adds '.txt' to the end of each filename before piping them to `xargs touch`.

By using the `-d '\n'` option with xargs (a GNU extension, which tells `xargs` to use only newline or '\n' as the delimiter rather than any whitespace, and disables quote processing) this even copes with filenames that have spaces and other potentially-problematic characters (except for `\n` or newline itself).  e.g. if a line contained 'abet able', without `-d '\n'`, two files (`abet` and `able.txt`) would be created.  With it, only one file `abet able.txt` will be created.

Comment: Thanks.  This answer is probably the easiest to understand.  sed and xargs were the two things I was missing.  I had the right conceptual stuff, just not the commands to do it.  xargs seems like a really powerful command.

Comment: yes, xargs is extremely useful.

Comment: using xargs is also more efficient than a for or while etc loop around touch - it executes only one `touch` command per many hundreds of filenames rather than one touch per filename.

Comment: Wow that's waaaaay more efficient.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an input redirection in a while loop with the read command

```
while read line; do
    touch "${line}.txt"
done < fileNames.txt
```

Comment: This is much cleaner and more portable than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Peschke, that is more portable (assuming Bourne-like shells), but not really cleaner. That won't work properly if the lines contain leading or trailing space or tabs, or start with `-`. That also means running one `touch` command per file.

Answer (score 1):

`awk 'NF>0' fileNames.txt | while read line; do touch "${line}.txt"; done`

The `awk` command just gets rid of the empty lines.

To the best of my knowledge, these lines are also literal, so whatever is on the line is getting written as a file name.

Comment: @Emmanuel Dieguez's answer should work as well (without using `awk`), but on extremely large files, removing empty lines before cycling through each one in a while loop may speed things up a bit.